# Dynamically Check and Create Table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having a problem creating a dynamic table in the database. If the table already exists in the database, then a new one should not be created.

```
if( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE abc")) == 1){
    echo "Already Exit";    
} else {
    //echo "not exit";
    $sql="CREATE TABLE `decoration`.`newtable` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,`company_id` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,`list_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,`created` INT NOT NULL ,`modified` INT NOT NULL ,`status` INT NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )) ENGINE = INNODB";
    if ($con->mysqli_query($sql)){
        echo "created";
    } else {
        echo "not created";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think people will struggle to understand your question here. What is the problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with below query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema`.`Employee` (
`idEmployee` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
`idAddresses` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idEmployee`) ,
CONSTRAINT `fkEmployee_Addresses`
FOREIGN KEY `fkEmployee_Addresses` (`idAddresses`)
REFERENCES `schema`.`Addresses` (`idAddresses`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_bin
```

`IF NOT EXISTS` will check the table exists or not and if table exists in the database it will not create new one.

Ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Hope this will help!